# redirection in exec() method in java

Tags: java, linux, redirect, exec

i dont get a proper answer..
my code is

```
String s="java  -classpath MiniRA/ RegAlloc < MiniRA/4.miniIR";
Process pro2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s); 
System.out.println("Okey");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro2.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
System.out.println("Okey");

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    text+=line;
text+="\n";
}
System.out.println(text);
```

but i get the result as an non terminated output window as

```
koha@ubuntu:~/pjt_new/P3$ java demo

Okey

Okey

^Z

[1]+  Stopped                 java demo

koha@ubuntu:~/pjt_new/P3$
```

Comment: the `<` symbol is used in `bash` (and other shells) to do input redirection. This does not work from the java command line. You need to use the `pro2.getInputStream()` and pass in your data.

Comment: but it works in terminal (cmd), but the problem is when it appears in the exec().